# How to show and hide html fieldset And also Set legend text from Asp.Net Code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, rad

I have a filedset and legend inside that with "some text" and inside this fieldset i have a GRID

I have 2 questions

1. How to show ? hide html filedset from code behind, i tried the following way to show and hide the field set

   a) set runat="server"--but it didnt work
    b) i pasted the fieldset inside an asp.net panel and tried to show/hide the panel, it
      also didnt work
2. How to set text for legend from code behind , ie I want to set 
   "some text" + Value_Form_Code Behind AS leged text

**Note :I am using "Rad Ajax Manager" and Rad Ajax LoadingPanel**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" >                
<fieldlset>
<legend><asp:Label id="Label1" runat="server" /></legend>
</fieldset>
</asp:Panel>
```

**How to show /hide html filedset from code behind ?**

```
Panel1.Visible = true; // or false
```

**How to set text for legend from code behind , ie I want to set "some text" + Value_Form_Code Behind AS legend text ?**

```
Label1.Text = String.Format("some text {0}",Value_Form_Code);
```

Answer (score 2):

it should also be possible to add an `ID` and `runat="server"` to your fieldset and control visibility through code-behind. Just remember to write 'ID' in upper letters.

```
<fieldset ID="myFieldset" runat="server">
```

You won't be able to control the legend text, unless you give it an ID and runat itself. But visibility is absolutely possible.

The upside of this approach is: no needless html markup (Panel would be extra div).
The downside: fieldsets are not really asp-controls, so some things might give you exceptions, so use carefully.

I use this approach only when I want to prevent controls from rendering at all in certain cases (visibility does that).

Answer (score 0):

**1:** I think you should put your fieldset inside an asp:panel and then hide/show the panel from your code-behind. This will automatically hide/show your fieldset.

**2:** As far as setting the legend text is concerned, just set the legend with runat="server" and set the code from codebehind.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the **'GroupingText'** property of the ***asp:panel*** control then It will render as the **'fieldset'** tag in HTML and whatever set in the   **'GroupingText'** property value is rendered as the `<legend>` tag.

I think following code will help you as per your requirement.

For Design side,

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel1" GroupingText="This is legend">
       <h4>Your Content Goes Here</h4>
    </asp:Panel>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnHidePanel" runat="server" Text ="Hide FieldSet" onclick="btnHidePanel_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnShowPanel" runat="server" Text ="Show FieldSet" onclick="btnShowPanel_Click" Visible="false" />
```

For Code-behind try this,

```
protected void btnHidePanel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Panel1.Visible = false;
            btnHidePanel.Visible = false;
            btnShowPanel.Visible = true;
        }

        protected void btnShowPanel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Panel1.Visible = true;
            Panel1.GroupingText = "This Legend Text Has been Changed";
            btnHidePanel.Visible = true;
            btnShowPanel.Visible = false;
        }
```